UEFI application doesn't read user input
I was trying to make a simple application using EDK2 that reads the user input and prints it out, but it doesn't work.
That's my source:
#include "UserInput.h"

EFI_STATUS EFIAPI UefiMain(IN EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {
  EFI_STATUS Status;
  EFI_INPUT_KEY Key;

  Print(L"Enter something: ");

  Status = SystemTable->ConIn->ReadKeyStroke(SystemTable->ConIn, &Key);
  if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
    Print(L"Failed to read user input\n");
    return Status;
  }

  Print(L"\nUser input: %c\n", Key.UnicodeChar);

  return EFI_SUCCESS;
}

Result is "Failed to read user input"

You need to add a call to WaitForEvent before you call ReadKeyStroke

Tried it right now, it still gives an error for me.

You have two options if you want to wait for the user input:

Poll until the user presses a key:

EFI_STATUS
ReadUserInputPoll(
    OUT CHAR16* Unicode)
{
    EFI_STATUS Status;
    EFI_INPUT_KEY Key;
    
    if (Unicode == NULL) {
        return EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    do {
        Status = gST->ConIn->ReadKeyStroke(gST->ConIn, &Key);
        if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
            if (Status != EFI_NOT_READY) {
                return Status;
            }
            // wait, check for timeout, ...
        }
    } while (EFI_ERROR(Status));

    *Unicode = Key.UnicodeChar;

    return Status;
}


Use the WaitForKey event:

EFI_STATUS
ReadUserInputWait(
    OUT CHAR16* Unicode)
{
    EFI_STATUS Status;
    EFI_INPUT_KEY Key;
    UINTN Index;

    if (Unicode == NULL) {
        return EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    // Combine this with a timer event if you don't want to wait forever
    Status = gBS->WaitForEvent(1, &gST->ConIn->WaitForKey, &Index);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        return Status;
    }

    Status = gST->ConIn->ReadKeyStroke(gST->ConIn, &Key);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        return Status;
    }

    *Unicode = Key.UnicodeChar;

    return Status;
}

